# FPDF ,Why do I get this error?

Tags: php, fpdf

So I made a script to extract some data from a mysql table, and create a PDF with it using the FPDF library,the script is working but it shows some '?' in the words,where special romanian characters such as 'ș','ț','ă','î' are supposed to be, so I thought to myself I will make an array and store the entire column in it and after create a for loop that will go over it and apply the `iconiconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2',$storeArray[$i]);` Here is the error I get:

> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\export_pdf.php on line 35
>
> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\export_pdf.php on line 35
>
> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\export_pdf.php on line 35
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 137 in C:\xampp\htdocs\export_pdf.php on
>   line 35 FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF
>   file

And here is my code:

```
<?php
require('mysql_table.php');


class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
    //Title
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
    $this->Cell(0,6,'Titlu',0,1,'C');
    $this->Ln(10);
    //Table header
    parent::Header();
}

}


//Connect to the database
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('dct_2015_2016');


$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

//Store into array column disciplina
$fetchcolumn = mysql_query("SELECT disciplina FROM nr_optiuni");
$storeArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetchcolumn,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $storeArray[] = $row['disciplina'];
}
for($i=0;$i<= count($storeArray); $i++){
    iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2',$storeArray[$i]);
}

$convert = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2','');



   //Table
$pdf->AddCol('semestru',20,'Semestru','C');
$pdf->AddCol('facultate',40,'Facultate');
$pdf->AddCol('opt_id',20,'Optiunea','C');
$pdf->AddCol('disciplina',100,iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2','Disciplină'),'L');
$pdf->AddCol('cati_au_ales',20,'Persoane','C');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table('select semestru,facultate,opt_id,disciplina,cati_au_ales from nr_optiuni order by semestru',$prop);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: You get the FPDF-Error since there was already 4 notices output by PDF, so it can't modify your header.

Comment: @Bioshade how can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure, IF those notices modify your data. You should check this.

To fix FPDF-Error you just need to do one thing: `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` This leads to your PHP-File not displaying any "errors" but real errors. So none of these Notices appear, this means no output, and this means FPDF can modify your header.

If this doesn't solve your problem: Double check if you use any file encoding using BOM. IF so, turn it off. BOM-File encoding outputs a single character on the beginning of the site, so FPDF cannot work, too. So if you file encoding is UTF-8 with BOM change it to UTF-8.

Comment: @Bioshade hope it works, I'm trying to get this to work since days now and Ițm on the point of giving up....
EDIT: Doesn't fix it.

Comment: Sad. Cannot tell you the problem since i can just give you advices based in what i know about your problem.